# Is there a way to import all databases into one database with Mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to gather automatically all my databases into one with Mysqldump, is there a way to do it ?

For example what I want is to **move all the tables from DB1, DB2 and DB3 into DB4** (*DB4 can already contain some tables or can be created during the import, it doesn't matter to me*).

I tried **mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > dump.sql**

Then import it with **mysql -uroot -p allInOne < dump.sql**

But the resulting database is only filled with it's own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to do the databases individually but with:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p DB1 > dump.sql
```

This will not include the Database name and Use in the dump so you can re-import into the new database.

If you really have a lot of databases then not sure if any of the other options will help :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Might be worth exploring:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --tables > dump.sql
```

Comment: `DB1 > dump.sql` works but I think a better way is to use `>>`. (`>` overwrites the .sql file, `>>` appends and, during the import, `<` appends in the database and `<<` isn't right. This solution may work for me, and the option --tables didn't solve anything. Thank you.